# create a dictionary using for loop than convert it into dataframe with indexing

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, for-loop, stock

```
def newtable():
    dict = {}
    col = ['DAYS','VWAP','TURNOVER','DEL_QTY']
    cal = [3,5,8,13]
    for i in col:
        for j in cal:
            value = final_3.iloc[:j,final_3.columns.get_loc(i)].sum()/j
            dict[i] = value
            print(pd.DataFrame(dict))
```

[image]

kindly help me out, i want 4 rows of each columns without duplicate values as shown in image.

Answer (score 0):

Drop duplicates after the dataframe has been made?

```
def newtable():
    adict = {}
    col = ['DAYS','VWAP','TURNOVER','DEL_QTY']
    cal = [3,5,8,13]
    for i in col:
        for j in cal:
            value = final_3.iloc[:j,final_3.columns.get_loc(i)].sum()/j
            adict[i] = value
            print(pd.DataFrame(adict).drop_duplicates())
```

Another way is to replace duplicates with NaN:

```
def newtable():
    adict = {}
    col = ['DAYS','VWAP','TURNOVER','DEL_QTY']
    cal = [3,5,8,13]
    for i in col:
        for j in cal:
            value = final_3.iloc[:j,final_3.columns.get_loc(i)].sum()/j
            adict[i] = value
            df = pd.DataFrame(adict)
            is_duplicate = df.apply(pd.Series.duplicated, axis=1)
            df = df.where(~is_duplicate, np.nan)
            print(df)
```